# Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, gradle

I have a project that has several `Build Variants` and for first build of Android Studio (with jdk 1.8 or 1.7, doesn't matter) it's failing with following errors but the strange part is for second run it's working, deeply annoying and time consuming:

> :app:transformClassesWithDexForBuildVariantDebug
>   Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.String[] using a local variable of type android.os.Bundle. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.io.InputStream using a local variable of type java.lang.String[]. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.io.InputStream using a local variable of type java.lang.String[]. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type boolean. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>   4 errors; aborting
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForBuildVariantDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
dexOptions {
    additionalParameters += ['--no-locals']
 }
```

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.